# How to access the indices of a tensorflow::tensor when using GPU device?

Tags: c++, c++11, tensorflow

I have implemented the standard tutorial of https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op.

```
class ZeroOutOp : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit ZeroOutOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
    // Grab the input tensor
    const Tensor& input_tensor = context->input(0);
    auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();
    ...

  }
}
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("ZeroOut").Device(DEVICE_GPU), ZeroOutOp);
```

But how to access the values of `input`:

```
auto input = input_tensor.flat<int32>();
```

Is there a problem with accesing GPU memory? I have tried several methods:

```
input(0,0); // segmentation fault

input.data()[0]; // segmentation fault 

Eigen::array<long,1> offset = {0};
Eigen::array<long,1> extent = {0}; 
input.slice(offset, extent) // does print an empty line

 const float *input = input_tensor.flat<float>().data();
 input[0]; // segmentation fault
```

---

Edit:

```
zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('./zero_out_cu.so')
with tf.Session(''):
  ipt = np.arange(1,7).reshape(3,2).astype('float32')
  to_check = zero_out_module.zero_out(ipt).eval()
```

The tensor size is 6, what is correct:

```
std::cout << input_tensor.flat<float>().size() << std::endl; // prints 6
```

Comment: Why not `auto input = input_tensor.flat<float>();` and `input(0)`? But maybe your `ìnput` is `nullptr`?

Comment: std::cout << input(0) << std::endl; // segmentation fault

Comment: Try `input.size()`? Is it 0?